# Need Morgan & Winston to log api response with btyesize

Tags: node.js, winston, morgan

I recently add Winston to my nodejs backend and combine it with morgan to log every API call. But I missed the bytesize properties which let me know how big each response size using morgan only. It could let me have a bigger picture which API is getting too much data. Any help will be great :)

Example of morgan api only

`GET /v1/users/notifications/5cb5ce7297fc767b4cdf667b?role=user&type=HUBFE&page_size=10&page_num=1 200 - 3252 - 25.553 ms`

Now implement with winston

`info: ::ffff:192.168.0.166 - - [02/Jul/2019:08:09:50 +0000] "GET /v1/searches/nearby?page_size=4&page_num=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost:8100/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1"
 {"timestamp":"2019-07-02 04:09:50 pm"}`

I am combining morgan and winston in my app.js file like this

```
app.use(morgan('combined', {
  stream: winston.stream
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: we can make changes in log format.

Use morgan-json and in json function use **:res[content-length] bytes** i.e.

```
const morgan = require('morgan');
const json = require('morgan-json');
const format = json(':method :url :status :res[content-length] bytes :response-time ms');
app.use(morgan(format));
```

Refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan#tokens for more log tokens

Comment: Good to know the format keyword is `bytes` for morgan. IMHO But I am combining morgan with winston.  Will it still work?